# How to execute actions directly from input radio button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

So I have this form with 3 buttons which after 1 is selected I can press the Filter button and the action Index is called, what I would like to do is somehow get rid of the need to have to press the Filter button and make it so the function Index is called when a radio button is checked, but as far as I know the form tag helpers asp-controller and asp-action don't really work on the input tag.

```
<form asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <input type="radio" name="category" asp-for="Category" value="Comedy" />Comedy<br />
    <input type="radio" name="category" asp-for="Category" value="Non-Comedy" />Non-Comedy<br />
    <input type="radio" name="category" asp-for="Category" value="All" />All<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do Jquery :

```
$("input[name='radio']").click(function() {
   $( "#MyForm" ).submit();
});
```